# Why am I obtaining this error pushing my code on GIT? Maybe is it a good idea create a branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I am trying to push a new version of my project on my repository using GIT (from the console) but I am obtaining this error message:

```
$ git push origin master
To https://bitbucket.org/MyUserName/glis-toolkit.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://MyUserName@bitbucket.org/MyUserName/glis-toolkit.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What it means? What means that "failed to push some refs"? What are these "refs"?

Another consideration to do is that the version on my BitBucket repository is a working version of my system (that now is pretty different from the local one).  I want to mantain it. Maybe is it better to create something like a branch for this new version?

If it could be a solution, how can I create a branch and push this new version on this branch?

Comment: There are commits on the server that you don't have locally, if you were to successfully push, there would be two tips on the server for your branch, which is not allowed. You need to learn what this means so that you can handle it appropriately. Most likely you can do `git pull origin master` to integrate the remote changes with your local changes and do a merge.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ok, only a doubt: before do the pull...can I check (using the GIT from the console) to check what are the difference between my local version and my remote one?

Comment: You can do `git fetch` then `git log master origin/master`, this should tell you what you would be merging in with `git pull`.

Comment: If you want to create a branch with your changes instead you can do: `git branch feature/new_branch` followed by `git reset master origin/master` (make sure none of the commands produce error messages, if they do, stop, and don't continue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use

```
git pull origin <your branch>
```

befor pushing code.
This might be happen because someone else also pushed some code on the branch and hence git asking forr first pulling those changes and the put your changes.

Comment: I know this option but the local one is not pretty different from the remote one so I really don't want risk to change something in the local one. I prefear to create a new remote branch and pushing the local one on it

Comment: Then make a copy first, then pull, then compare both. But usually pulling is enough as your local changes should be kept, there may be some collision as well when local and remote are different in the same place.

Comment: @AndreaNobili you can create a temporary branch if you want to save your changes